# GCC error _Pragma fires if it appears in an intermediate preprocessing step?

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor, pragma

The following code, if preprocessed with `gcc -E`, produces some errors from `_Pragma("GCC error")`:

```
_Pragma("GCC error \"ERROR\"") // error

#define MACRO_ERROR _Pragma("GCC error \"MACRO_ERROR\"")
MACRO_ERROR // error

#define VOID(arg)
VOID(_Pragma("GCC error \"VOID_ERROR\"")) // no error

#define MACRO_VOID_ERROR VOID(_Pragma("GCC error \"MACRO_VOID_ERROR\""))
MACRO_VOID_ERROR // no error

#define FORWARD(macro, arg) macro(arg)
FORWARD(VOID, _Pragma("GCC error \"FORWARD_VOID_ERROR\"")) // error

#define MACRO_FORWARD_VOID_ERROR FORWARD(VOID, _Pragma("GCC error \"MACRO_FORWARD_VOID_ERROR\""))
MACRO_FORWARD_VOID_ERROR // error
```

`FORWARD(VOID, _Pragma("GCC error \"FORWARD_VOID_ERROR\""))` and `MACRO_FORWARD_VOID_ERROR` produce errors although the pragma operator is **not** in the final expansion (which is empty).

Is this expected behavior?

In comparison, `VOID(_Pragma("GCC error \"VOID_ERROR\""))` and `MACRO_VOID_ERROR` do not produce errors. It seems like this is because the pragma operator is "preprocessed away quick enough" with these.

What is the rule behind this?

Previously, I was assuming that the pragma operator is without an effect if it shows up in intermediate expansion steps only. Obviously that is wrong, at least for my `gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4)`.

Output of `gcc -E` (empty lines removed):

```
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<built-in>"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "/usr/include/stdc-predef.h" 1 3 4
# 1 "<command-line>" 2
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 1 "<stdin>"
<stdin>:1:11: error: ERROR
# 1 "<stdin>"
# 4 "<stdin>"
<stdin>:4:11: error: MACRO_ERROR
# 4 "<stdin>"
# 13 "<stdin>"
<stdin>:13:11: error: FORWARD_VOID_ERROR
# 13 "<stdin>"
# 16 "<stdin>"
<stdin>:16:11: error: MACRO_FORWARD_VOID_ERROR
# 16 "<stdin>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually is as expected (or at least, what I would expect), although it's unintuitive because you're mixing expression-level side effects into a language that was originally designed to be completely side-effect-free and partially lazy.

Referring to the C standard rather than to GCC's documentation, we can find the following in [6.10.3.1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=186):

> A parameter  in  the  replacement  list,  unless  preceded by a `#` or `##` preprocessing token or followed by a `##` preprocessing token (see below), is
>   replaced  by  the  corresponding  argument  after  all  macros  contained  therein  have  been expanded.    Before   being   substituted,   each  argument’s   preprocessing   tokens   are completely  macro  replaced  as  if  they formed  the  rest  of  the  preprocessing  file;  no  other preprocessing tokens are available.

The key piece of ambiguous phrasing here is that the standard only says that an argument is expanded ("as if it formed the rest of the file") *before being substituted*. It does not explicitly say that an argument needs to be expanded if it isn't going to be substituted at all, and since the first part of the paragraph makes it clear that how an argument is handled depends on the context in which it is actually used by the macro, this is a fair optimization to make (pretty necessary for handling complex metaprogramming libraries like Boost, as well).

"As if they formed the rest of the file" is key for why the execution of the `_Pragma` operator should happen before the substitution into an argument: [5.1.1.2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf#page=29) lists `_Pragma` execution as belonging the same phase as macro replacement, so if replacement is applied to a given token sequence, which it definitely is when the argument *is* substituted, so should `_Pragma` execution.

So it is completely unsurprising that the `_Pragma` should run in the `FORWARD` case, because it needs to be evaluated, and its effects applied, two steps before the `VOID` macro is picked up for expansion during rescan. It's potentially ambiguous whether it should be applied in the case of the direct call to `VOID`, but since the standard explicitly has macros decide how to handle an argument based on how the argument is used, it makes sense that it should be allowed for an argument that is completely *un*used to never be evaluated at all, even though this is not specified directly.